# Как связать html с Python?

Tags: python, html, aiohttp

У меня есть HTML код, который запускается как веб приложение на aiohttp(python). Как обратиться к данным, которые вводит пользователь? То есть мне необходимо интегрировать введенные данные в мой скрипт на языке Python, как это сделать?

```js
const sendMessage = () => {
        alert('Please wait for the scanning!');
    }
```

```css
html {
            font-family: Verdana, "sans-serif";
        }

        body {
            min-height: 100vh;
            background: black no-repeat;
        }

        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: white;
            text-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.8);
        }

        #root {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
        }

        #messages {
            width: 70%;
        }

        .message {
            background-color: white;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
            -moz-transition: 0.3s;
            transition: 0.3s;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .message:hover {
            -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
            -moz-transition: 0.3s;
            transition: 0.3s;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }

        .message__created {
            font-size: 12px;
            color: darkgrey;
            text-align: right;
        }

        .message__text {
            font-size: 20px;
            color: black;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        .message__ratings {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 400;
            margin-top: 5px;
        }

        .form {
            width: 70%;
            margin-bottom: 20px;

             display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            gap: 20px;

        }

        .form__button {
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 150px;
            background-color: white;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .form__input, .form__button {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: 18px;
            outline: none;
            border: none;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 15px;
            -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
            -moz-transition: 0.3s;
            transition: 0.3s;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }

        .form__input:focus, .form__button:hover {
            -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
            -moz-transition: 0.3s;
            transition: 0.3s;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            box-shadow: 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        }
```

```html
<div>
    <h1>Port Scanner</h1>
    <div id="root">
        <div class="form">
            <input id="message_text" class="form__input" type="text"
                   placeholder="IP adress"/>
            <input id="message_text1" class="form__input" type="text"
                   placeholder="Range of ports"/>
            <div class="form__button" onclick="sendMessage()">Scan</div>
        </div>
        <div id="messages">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Для того, чтобы обрабатывать данные форм, используй AJAX запросы. через JS отправляй запрос на бэкэнд, обрабатывай и возвращай ответ, далее по этому ответу уже выполняй любую логику на странице

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скачай pyscript, на официальном сайте вам все покажут как его привязать к html

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/817842)

Comment: @NowhereMan, чем плох ответ? Подсказал свою мысль какую технологию использовать. А всю работу выполнять за того, кто задал вопрос вовсе не обязательно

Comment: @SergeyK., а где здесь ответ?

Comment: @NowhereMan, так я и так подсказал ему ответ, если не устраивает ответ тогда напишите сами полностью, я ему подсказал скачать определенный инструмент для выполнения его вопроса

Comment: Не устраивает качество ответа, так как совет "скачать инструмент" без какого-то наглядного примера использования этого инструмента для решения заданного вопроса не является ответом по сути.  И вообще, складывается впечатление, что здесь оба-два аккаунта принадлежат одному человеку.

Comment: @NowhereMan, Ваше впечатление - Ваше дело. Странно создать новый аккаунт, дать первый ответ, затем с более старого и опытного защищать себя) Тем более, что я в комментарии предложил совершенно иной ответ.

Comment: С чего вы взяли что я создавал другие аккаунты здесь? Я здесь недавно зарегался как бы

Comment: И если это у вас такое впечатление то это ваши проблемы что вы видите так. Я здесь подобного не вижу